# Changing one column in a dataset

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataset

I am writing out a few lines in a database to a text document. I have everything set except for the date field. I need to change it to MM-dd-yy but the results I keep getting is the default in the DB, which is MM/dd/yyy HH:mm:ss (7/8/2013 2:01:05 PM). The date column is in the middle of the table and I have been trying everything I can think of from adding an if statement to breaking it up into three parts but none of it changes just the date column.  Below is how I am pulling the data and writing it. This then shows 2 ints, a string, the date, a string and one more int. The order is fine its just changing the date.

edit: It writes all the correct data, it just doesn't show the date the way I want it.

```
foreach (DataRow row in jackTDataSet.Tables[0].Select(quer))
{
    foreach (object item in row.ItemArray)
    {
            writer.Write(String.Format("{0,-10}", item.ToString() + ""));
    }
    writer.WriteLine("\t");
}
```

Comment: did you try checking the value using MessageBox.Show or Response.Write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this, how ever you run the risk that one of the other columns could potentially be parsed as a DateTime, and get formatted MM-dd-yy.  Personally would rework your iteration on this. IF** you are selecting all the columns in your query and it is static and doesn't change (Which is not likely I know but putting out all options here) you could iterate based off the column names shown in the second for loop on this post.

```
foreach (object item in row.ItemArray)
{
     DateTime parsed;
     if (DateTime.TryParse(item.ToString(), out parsed))
     {
          writer.Write(String.Format("{0,-10}", parsed.ToString("MM-dd-yy") + ""));
     }
     else 
     {
          writer.Write(String.Format("{0,-10}", item.ToString() + ""));
     }
}



foreach (DataColumn col in jackTDataSet.Tables[0].Columns)
{
     if (col.ColumnName == "Name of date Field ")
     {
         writer.Write(String.Format("{0,-10}", ((DateTime)row[col.ColumnName]).ToString("MM-dd-yy") + ""));
     }
     else 
     {
         writer.Write(String.Format("{0,-10}", row[col.ColumnName].ToString() + ""));
     }
}
```

Comment: The worked wonderfully. I am calling all the columns and for now it is static. Thanks.